# Discord py bot got temporarily banned because of exceeding the limit when it only makes 1 http request every 15 mins?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I made a command "!initmemes" that would check if the context channel name was "memes" and if it was, the bot would start sending a random embedded message meme off of Reddit every 15 minutes to the channel.

```
@bot.command()
async def initmemes(ctx):
  if str(ctx.message.channel) == "memes":
    funny_embed = discord.Embed(description="✅ Initializing *the funny*... Expect to see memes!")
    await ctx.send(embed = funny_embed)
    while True:
      await asyncio.sleep(900)
      subreddit = await reddit_asyncpraw.subreddit(random.choice(ans.meme_subs))
      submission_list = [submission async for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=15) if not submission.stickied and not submission.over_18 and not submission.spoiler]
      selector = random.randint(0, len(submission_list) - 1)
      p = submission_list[selector]
      reddit_embed=discord.Embed(title=str(p.title), url="https://reddit.com"+str(p.permalink), color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 69, 0))
      reddit_embed.set_footer(text=str(p.score), icon_url=ans.reddit_upvote)
      reddit_embed.set_author(name="u/"+str(p.author), url="https://www.reddit.com/user/"+str(p.author))
      reddit_embed.set_image(url=p.url)
      await ctx.send(embed = reddit_embed)
```

I am very confused why using this command got my bot temporarily banned from accessing the Discord API even though it only makes 1 http request every 15 minutes?

How can I limit the amount of http requests my bot can make in an x amount of time so it doesn't get banned again?

Comment: Are you hosting the bot yourself or are you using some other service to host it? Maybe the host's IP makes too many requests and got rate limited. I've heard of repl.it having an issue with this.

Comment: It's hosted on repl.it, do you know a fix?

Comment: Besides switching your host, no sorry.